# Java variable declaration current standards

Tags: java, java-8

I will shorty be attempting my OCA and I have been getting mixed information about how to correctly declare Longs and Floats.

As of JavaSE8 How does one correctly declare a Long and a Float as in with the additional L or F at the end of the value for the cast or is this no longer necessary?

Comment: I never declare my longs because it doesn't really affect the program behavior, and the compiler takes care of them. But I declare the floats because these can change how divisions operate.

Comment: @Aragorn Even for the OCA 8 exam?

Comment: *"As of JavaSE8"* What change in Java 8 do you believe changes anything on this topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `L` for `long` literals and `F` for `float` literals wherever the difference from `int` and `double` matters. **Always** is a good safeguard against forgetting when it matters.

Quoting Java 8 Language Specification for [Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` ([§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)).
>
> *The suffix `L` is preferred, because the letter `l` (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit `1` (one).*

And [Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type `float` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter `D` or `d` ([§4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)).